# Problema con el paquete "mlogit"

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de crear un modelo de elección y para eso quiero usar la librería "mlogit" y el código que he usado es el siguiente

`coches.mlogit <- mlogit.data(data=coches, choice="choice", shape="long",  varying=5:8, alt.var="alt")`

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

```
Error in dfidx::dfidx(data = data, dfa$idx, drop.index = dfa$drop.index,  : 
  for data in wide format, providing id2 is irrelevant
```

He leído que el problema estaba en que `mlogit.data is deprecated, use dfidx::dfidx() instead` y por lo tanto el argumento `varying` es el que me estaba causando el error, ya que dfdix asume que mi base de datos está en un formato ancho y por tanto recomiendan quitarlo.

Por lo tanto lo he quitado y si que se me ha ejecutado pero me ha aparecido un nuevo problema ya que al abrir la nueva base de datos creada me da error al cargarlo y sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, start:min(NROW(x), start + len)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es casi imposible ayudarte si no podemos reproducir el problema. Puedes mostrar al menos la estructura de tus datos: `str(coches)`